# Can't get class project FTP server to send 226

Tags: java, ftp

For a class project, I'm coding up a FTP client in Java (no external FTP libraries allowed) that can connect and grab files from a school FTP server.  For some reason, once a transfer is complete, the server will not send 226, nor will it close the connection from it's own end.

The only way to make the server send 226 is to close the InputStream from the client side manually, which seems unsafe in case since the client cannot be 100% sure when the file has finished transferring.  (Right now, InputStream's available() method is what's being used to check how far along the transfer is.)

In the project specification, it says that we **must** follow RFC requirements where applicable for the subset of commands we are implementing.  The RFC states this:

*In general, it is the server's responsibility to maintain the data
      connection--to initiate it and to close it.  The exception to this
      is when the user-DTP is sending the data in a transfer mode that
      requires the connection to be closed to indicate EOF.  The server
      MUST close the data connection under the following conditions:
   1. The server has completed sending data in a transfer mode
            that requires a close to indicate EOF.
   2. The server receives an ABORT command from the user.
   3. The port specification is changed by a command from the
            user.
   4. The control connection is closed legally or otherwise.
   5. An irrecoverable error condition occurs.
      Otherwise the close is a server option, the exercise of which the
      server must indicate to the user-process by either a 250 or 226
      reply only.*

Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT: The server running is ProFTPD 1.3.0a Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which transfer mode are you using? To quote from RFC959:

> The stream transfer mode is inherently
>   unreliable, since one can not
>   determine if the connection closed
>   prematurely or not.  The other
>   transfer modes (Block, Compressed) do
>   not close the connection to indicate
>   the end of file.  They have enough FTP
>   encoding that the data connection can
>   be parsed to determine the end of the
>   file. Thus using these modes one can
>   leave the data connection open for
>   multiple file transfers.

Are you using Block or Compressed?

EDIT - Oh - stream

I didn't take it in on the first read, but you say you are using `InputStream.available()` to see how far the transfer is through? That is not what that method does. In this case it returns the number of bytes that have been recieved by the computer but not yet processed by the application. The value returned could be anywhere from zero to the full size of the file.

If you are assuming the file is completely sent when `available()` returns 0, you are stopping reading too early - which is why the server is not closing the socket and sending 226.

The only way to tell if the file is completely sent is to test the return from a `read` operation from the stream. If it is -1 the file is complete. A read into a byte array can read zero bytes. It is unusual but allowed. Typical code to read from an input stream until the input is closed would look like this:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int read;
    while( (read=in.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
        System.out.println("Read "+read +" bytes from socket ("+
               in.available()+" available now)");
    }
```

Comment: Oh :( **thinks** Ah :) I have just notice something, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Anon,

This post is all just my personal opinion.

I was your university lecturer I would be happy if you where to just closed the apparently exhuasted stream on the client side, and then handled the subsequent 226... AS LONG AS YOU COMMENTED WHY DID THAT, especially pointing out that it's a "work around" for an apparent deviation from the published protocol by the schools FTP service. I.e: "Not my problemo, I just gotta deal with it. K Boss?"

For a triple-bonus word score: 
1. Code your client to work with both the standard server (get an FTP server running on your box to test against, there's free ones for every O/S) as well as your schools "apparently dodgy" FTP server... and 
2. Find out exactly what the schools FTP server is ($10 says it's some profs home-grown piece of superperformant soooo-non-standard extretia) and then see if you can confirm that this is in a known issue with that implementation... and If it isn't then lodge a bug report with the author(s).

I'm just guessing this is the prof's "twist in the tail"... to see who's upto a "real world challenge".

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I'm not here to complain, I just want to know if there is something I've missed.

Comment: To which my answer is "No, I don't think so" but of course it's impossible to tell without a lot more information. Like I say: find out if it's a known issue with the schools FTP server. If is you're well justified in "hacking around it".